# Is Sandforce SF-2200 hardware level Garbage Collection enough?

Tags: ssd, trim

If I have a SSD with a sandforce SF-2200 controller do I need to worry about TRIM support? Is the hardware level garbage collection sophisticated enough to not worry about this?

Comment: Such questions depend a lot on what you're doing. Are you using your computer for your day job of editing video, 60 hours/week, or just for checking Facebook?

Comment: At the moment it depends on the used firmware version if TRIM works correctly. Please read http://www.tweaktown.com/articles/4870/lsi_sandforce_5_series_ssd_firmware_trim_lost_and_found_performance_investigated/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the algorithm, TRIM command will help reduce the Garbage Collection workload because it invalidates the data in the trimmed blocks. From firmware/hw implementation of view, there would be one more list to take care, but that will be compensated by the time saved by skipping the Read-Program cycle. So it will help reduce the Write Amplification too.